# How do I increase the validation accuracy of my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am making an image classification model with around 2445 images and 21 categories. I am unable to increase the validation accuracy from 68%.

The input image size is reconverted to 75 x 75 pixels in grayscale. The architecture uses two hidden convolution layers and I have tried adding another identical layer which hasn't helped in increasing the validation accuracy.

How can I manipulate the pixel size or the architecture to increase the validation accuracy?

The 20th epoch output is:

```
loss: 0.0694 - acc: 0.9779 - val_loss: 1.6924 - val_acc: 0.6801'''
```

the architecture of the model is

```
model=Sequential()
```

First layer

```
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
```

Second Layer

```
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(64)) 
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(num_classes)) 
model.add(Activation("softmax")) 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y_new,batch_size=32 ,epochs = 20, validation_split=0.1
```

Comment: The dropouts for convolutional layers are almost worthless, Use it at FC layers.
Looks like model may be overfitting, hence appropriate use of dropouts or L1/L2 regularization can be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are all your 2445 images evenly distributed among 21 classes?
2. Standardise/Normalise your data. (Preprocess)

```
  mean = np.mean(x_train)               
  stddev = np.std(x_train)
  x_train = (x_train - mean)/stddev
  x_test =  (x_test - mean)/stddev
```

3. Use 'BatchNormalisation' to normalise your data after every layer.

Answer (score 0):

actually the image transformation into grayscale or change in it's pixels is not handled by layers of the keras model, it depends on what data are you passing for training and what pre-processing you are doing(if any). So check the input data here X and y_new or show that part of code in the question itself.